# Is there any epub sdk or package for flutter that supports highlights and notes?

Tags: flutter, highlight, epub, epub3, ebook-reader

I want to make an Epub Reader with text highlighting, notes, and other annotations. I can't seem to find any free sdk or package that support my needs.

[vocsy_epub_viewer](https://pub.dev/packages/vocsy_epub_viewer) is an option but the reader is not customizable and there aren't any docs to help out. What are my options?

Answer (score 0):

Try it here: https://github.com/Mantano/iridium?tab=readme-ov-file.
Currently, there is no implementation for "Highlights/annotations", but it is listed in the to-do list.